# F# find elements in array1 that are also in array2

Tags: arrays, f#

Say `array1=[|1;2;3;4;5;6|],array2=[|7;6;5;4;3|]`
basically, I want an array which contains the common elements of array1 and array2 AND in the sorted as array1.
In this case, I should return array `[|3;4;5;6|]`.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You should really start to show some more effort in these questions - at least somethink like: I tried `...` but it produces this incorrect result / compiler error etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
 array1 |> Array.filter (fun t -> array2 |> Array.exists (fun t2 -> t=t2))
```

this gets the correct sort order for free.